# Get figure handle from different mfile and plot in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am tasked to design a GUI and I need to use variables and plots from a different mfile which I created earlier. I'm pretty confident about getting variables from the processing mfile but I'm not sure how to get the plots/figures.

So basically my question is whether I can get() a figure from my mfile and then set() an axes to that figure inside my GUI.

Note: The reason I am doing this is because I want to keep the processing of data separate from the GUI mfile. I could just dump all the processing in the callback of my process button but that's not good. I would also appreciate good coding practices for my case since I have never worked with GUI's before (only scripting with PHP and MATLAB)

Note2 (rundown of what has to be done): In the GUI we basically are supposed to load 2 files, we then press the "process" button and then 4 plots have to appear. All the processing code already exists in a previously written mfile (by me).

Thanks! :)

Comment: I figured it out myself!

What I did was use gcf to get the current figure like so:

output.worldmap = gcf

I then passed the object back like so:
setappdata(0,'output',output)

and grabbed it again inside my callback function like so:
getappdata(0,'output')
and used the following function to set the axes
set(output.worldmap,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes_worldmap)

I also made sure that the correct axis was set before I actually ran my mfile which does the processing with axes(handles.worldmap)

Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself! What I did was use gcf to get the current figure like so: `output.worldmap = gcf` I then passed the object back like so: `setappdata(0,'output',output)` and grabbed it again inside my callback function like so: `getappdata(0,'output')` and used the following function to set the axes `set(output.worldmap,'CurrentAxes',handles.axes_worldmap)` I also made sure that the correct axis was set before I actually ran my mfile which does the processing with `axes(handles.worldmap)`